# Nginx, rewrite multiple subfolders

Tags: apache, nginx, url-rewriting

I try to move my server from Apache towards a Nginx based setting. However, I get into problems getting a part of my htaccess Apache magic to work in Nginx.

The .htaccess code I would like to transfer is:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$                  /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+).html$              /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)/.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$       /index.php?page=$1&id=$2&sub=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)/.*$       /index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

I used an [online converter](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess) that gave me the following location block:

```
location / {
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ /index.php?page=$1 break;
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+).html$ /index.php?page=$1 break;
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)/.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ /index.php?page=$1&id=$2&sub=$3 break;
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)/.*$ /index.php?page=$1&id=$2 break;
}
```

Sadly, I'm only able to get a single location rewrite to be working at a time (the one I put "last;" behind). I don't seem to be able to do this dynamic rewriting of a multiple subfolder URL into arguments for a single PHP script.

Any help on this? What is the Nginx way of doing such a rewrite? I tried using several location's for different subfolders but I would rather have a generic solution that work no-matter what url's are thrown at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a different location block for each rule:

```
location ~ ^/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/$ {
    rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ /index.php?page=$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+.html$ {
    rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+).html$ /index.php?page=$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/[0-9]+/.*/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$ {
    rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)/.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ /index.php?page=$1&id=$2&sub=$3 last;
}

location ~ ^/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/[0-9]+/.*$ {
    rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)/.*$ /index.php?page=$1&id=$2 last;
}

location = /index.php {
    # your proxy rules here...
}
```

The *rewrite* rules above use the *last* option, which is explained in the [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html):

```
last
    stops processing the current set of ngx_http_rewrite_module
    directives and starts a search for a new location matching the
    changed URI;
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! I didn't tried using regular expression in the location line.